# Simple Injector + Fluent Nhibernate wiith UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, unit-of-work, simple-injector

I'm using the Simple Injector with Fluent Nhibernate. I recorded the "Session" in SimpleInjectorInitializer file with the following code:

```
var container = Bootstrapper.

container.Register(() => Core.Core.Dados.NH.NhSessionFactory.Current.OpenSession(),
    new SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebRequestLifestyle());
```

However, the session is through the builder in my "UnitOfWork," that she was registered, there is always a single instance of "Session" active, caused some errors when handling objects, as "a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session ".
How can I work the "Session" with the Nhiberante UnitOfWork to avoid this problem?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question and add additional details (such as stack trace information and usage), because your question is currently too broad and its unclear what the exact problem is.

Comment: I resolve...

I improved my architecture, enriching my domain and decreasing the responsibilities of the "Controller", leaving the service hold consultations and altareções. Because I was using AutoMapper to manipulate the DTO par Model objects, which caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while looking for a solution to using Simple Injector with Fluent nhibernate (while switching from Ninject to Simple Injector). This example does not use Unit Of Work pattern because really nHibernate's **Session** **is** **Unit of Work** container. This is how it can be done (ASP.NET MVC exmple)

SessionProvider

```
public class SessionProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory()); }
    }

    public SessionProvider(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

       return Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(_connectionString)
                    .Driver<ProfiledSQLiteClientDriver>)
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => cfg.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false"))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
        var sessionProvider = new SessionProvider(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlite"].ConnectionString);

        var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), new[] { typeof(Repository<>).Assembly });
        container.RegisterSingleton<ICommandDispatcher>(new CommandDispatcher(container));
        container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] { typeof(UserCommandsHandler).Assembly });
        /* here comes Session wiring ....*/
        container.Register(() => sessionProvider.SessionFactory, Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ISession>(()=> container.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession(), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```